# Is it possible to test if a number is either even or '1', using only bitwise operators?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Is it possible to achieve using only bitwise operators, ie without logical/comparison/relation operators?

This would essentially be equivalent to the following.

```
(a & 1 == 0) || (a == 1)
```

I accept that in many languages a final equality comparison may need to be done to convert the result to a true/false value, but I am not considering that in the question.
An answer which accepts an input bit array and returns the same output bit array for an even number as for '1' is essentially what I am after. Either that or a reason why it is not possible.

Comment: Not an answer but I guess the first test (`a & 1`) returns whether the number is odd.

Comment: My mistake, updated the example to be correct

Comment: please specify the language

Comment: Language agnostic question, for the purposes of gaining a greater understanding of the potential of bitwise operations

Comment: Anything that behaves differently for a specific numeric value cannot possibly be implemented solely using bitwise operators, as equality to that specific value is a property of all the bits taken together, yet bitwise operators treat each bit position in isolation.  You could possibly do this in assembly language, where you have flag bits that get set based on the whole result without having to do any explicit non-bitwise test (XOR value with 1, result is Zero flag OR low bit of value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would not recommend to do this at all, but I was able to achieve it in C, but with only making `a` to be an`unsigned char`. It could work with others too, but that would lengthen the condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (unsigned char a = 0; a < 255; a++) {
        if ((~a & 1) | (1 >> (a & 0x0E | a >> 4)))
            printf ("%d is even or 1\n", a);
        else
            printf("%d is odd\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`(~a & 1)` will yield `1` if `a` is even. `(a & 0x0E | a >> 4)` will yield `0` when `a` is either `1` or `0`. Therefore in those cases `(1 >> (a & 0x0E | a >> 4)))` will be `(1 >> 0)` which is `1`, otherwise the shift value is between `1` and `15` so making the expression `0`.

My initial approach was `(1 >> (a >> 1))`, but soon realized this cause shift overflow, since the shift amount exceed the max possible. And not just raising that warning, but actually falsely recognize every `n * 64 + 1` values as even. So the more complicated approach is there to limit the shift amount to be less than `64` by OR -ing `a` upper 4 bit with its lower 4 bit, but setting the LSB to `0`. This resulting number is `<= 15` and only `0` when `a` is `1` or `0` just as needed.

Answer (score 2):

`((a & 1) == 0) | (a == 1)` works. No need to do any complex tricks

Comment: `(a & 1 == 0)` seems a logical operator to me

Comment: @RobertKock who said that `==` is a [logical operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_operator)? [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), [C/C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and other languages all disagree with you. In Java and C# you can't even get a logical expression without a relational operator. `if (a & 1)` or `if (a && 1)` won't compile in those languages

Comment: `==` has higher precedence than `&`, you need more brackets.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev thanks. I've copied directly from the OP's code

Comment: @phuclv Hmm C disagree? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators. Okay. OP clearly want bitwise operators here, so why we pretend he is not?

Comment: @Eraklon pretend what? The OP wants some way without logical operators

Comment: @phuclv Pretending `==` is not a logical operator.

Comment: @Eraklon because `==` is not a logical operator. Even in C

Comment: @phuclv Okay so seems all of the internet is wrong here and `==` is not a logical operator (wondering then what it might be?). Can you enlight us?

Comment: @Eraklon please read the links in my comments above, they all say that `==` is a relational/conditional operator

Comment: @phuclv Ohh I see now. Well you are right. But for lot of people including myself logical is the ones which return is a logical value (even if by definition its not). So by definition your answer may right, but I have that gut feeling OP want it with only bitwise operators which exclude relationals too.

Comment: I was considering `==` to be a logical operator, though I will accept that my semantics were not 100% correct. +1 for the technically correct answer, though I was searching for a purely bitwise solution just to satisfy curiosity.
I will update the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, but in the Intel64/AMD64/x86_64 instruction set, it is easy to perform a sequence of bitwise operations that will both return a value and a condition code flag that allows the proposed comparison.

Assume that the input value is in the %rax register.

```
MOV %rax, %r8     # replicate input value into %r8
MOV %rax, %r9     # replicate input value into %r9
AND $0x1, %r8     # AND 0x1 with the contents of %r8 and put result in %r8
XOR $0x1, %r9     # XOR 0x1 with the contents of %r9 and put result in %r9
OR  %r8, %r9      # OR %r8 with %r9 and put result in %r9
```

The AND operation will return 0 if the input is even, otherwise it will return 1.
The XOR operation will return 0 iff the input is 0x1, otherwise it returns non-zero.
The OR operation will return 0 iff both %r8 and %r9 are zero, otherwise it returns non-zero.

Each of the bitwise operations sets various condition flags.  The relevant one here is called "ZF", which is set to 1 iff the result of the operation is 0.

The ZF flag set by the final operation can be used to control a conditional branch.  Use "JZ" (Jump if Zero) to branch if ZF=1 (i.e., the condition is true) or "JNZ" (Jump if Not Zero) to branch if the condition is not true.

You can save the result from %r9 to memory and use it later in a comparison against zero (true) or not zero (false).

You can also act on the result without using a conditional branch instruction -- the same condition code can be used to control a conditional move instruction.  The CMOVE instruction will copy an an input operand in memory or in a register to an output register iff ZF=1, or CMOVNE will perform the copy iff ZF=0.  For example, you could copy the value "1" from a source register to a destination register iff the condition was true, then accumulate the destination register values into an accumulator.  The accumulator will then contain the count of cases for which the comparison returned "True".

Comment: One can also use the output values to create masks in either SSE/AVX/AVX2 style (only the most significant bit in each field of the SIMD register is used as the mask control bit) or AVX512 style (masks are held in a separate set of mask registers).  Lots of bit shifting, merging, and value negation are required, but no explicit comparison instructions would be required.

Answer (score 0):

A method that works for any fixed (power-of-two) bit width is to use the following function which returns 1 when all bits are set and 0 otherwise:

```
uint32_t allOnes(uint32_t a) {
    a &= a >> 1;
    a &= a >> 2;
    a &= a >> 4;
    a &= a >> 8;
    a &= a >> 16;
    return a;
}
```

We can then do the check as follows:

```
uint32_t f1(uint32_t a) {
    return (~a & 1) | allOnes(a ^ ~uint32_t(1));
}
```